# Which grails-maven-plugin version is compatible with Maven 3.0.4?

Tags: maven, grails, maven-plugin, grails-plugin

I have a project running grails 2.3.9 and right now I'm using the following `grails-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <grailsVersion>2.3.9</grailsVersion>
        <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
        <fork>false</fork>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

But when I try to run some mvn command I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:clean (default-clean) on project my-portal: The plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

I'm not able to upgrade my Maven version right now, so I need to run `grails-maven-plugin` compatible with Maven 3.0.4.

Where can I find the compatible version for `grails-maven-plugin` to run it with Maven 3.0.4?

Comment: Have you tried using the same version as Grails version? i,e: `2.3.9`

Comment: There is no 2.3.9 version for grails-maven-plugin

Comment: I see it. I fear we are at loss here because you cannot use 3.0.4. You might have to downgrade maven to 2.2.1 at the least by using Grails 2.3.8. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.4.3 of the `grails-maven-plugin` requires Maven 3.1.0. This is defined as a pre-requisite in the `pom.xml` of that plugin ([source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/blob/v2.4.3/pom.xml#L47-L48)).

The change was made in [this commit](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/commit/36264f026a244edb8cb88059b76a592d7cec7eb0#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036) between version [2.3.8](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/blob/v2.3.8/pom.xml#L47-L48) and [2.4.0](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven/blob/v2.4.0/pom.xml#L47-L48).

Since you mentioned you can't upgrade Maven, you need to downgrade to version 2.3.8 (at most) of `grails-maven-plugin` which only requires a Maven version of at least 2.0.5.

Comment: I am getting  the same error, my grails version is 2.4.2 and java version 1.7. Maven 3.1.0. Any idea why the reason would be?